# ReferenceError: Response is not defined with msw/node + Vitest

Tags: typescript, vitest, msw

Was wondering if anyone has encountered the following issue with the latest `msw` (2.0.9) and trying to run it with the latest Vite (`5.0.2`) + Vitest (`0.34.6`)? No matter what I do, I cannot get past this error of `Response` somehow being undefined despite having `cross-fetch` installed as well along with `@types/node`.

My installed TypeScript version is `5.3.2` which doesn't satisfy the `peerDependency` of `msw` which is set up to `5.2.x`, but I did downgrade it to meet the requirements and I was still met with the same error.

```
ReferenceError: Response is not defined
 ❯ node_modules/.pnpm/msw@2.0.9_typescript@5.3.2/node_modules/msw/lib/core/HttpResponse.mjs:5:28
 ❯ src/setupTests.ts:3:31
      1| import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
      2| import fetch from "cross-fetch";
      3| import { setupServer } from "msw/node";
       |                               ^
```

For reference, my `vite.config.ts` is the following:

```js
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { configDefaults } from "vitest/config";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    host: true,
    port: 4000,
  },
  define: {
    "process.env": {
      VERSION: process.env.VERSION,
      PLAYWRIGHT: process.env.PLAYWRIGHT,
      USE_MSW: process.env.USE_MSW,
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    mainFields: ["module"],
    alias: {
      src: "/src",
    },
  },
  test: {
    environment: "jsdom",
    globals: true,
    setupFiles: "./src/setupTests.ts",
    watch: false,
    // Need to concat with config defaults otherwise node_modules get tested
    exclude: [...configDefaults.exclude, "src/e2e/*"],
    coverage: {
      provider: "istanbul",
      exclude: [".eslintrc.cjs", "src/index.tsx", "playwright.config.ts", ".github/*"],
      all: true,
      lines: 100,
      functions: 100,
      branches: 100,
      statements: 100,
      reporter: ["json", "lcov", "text", "cobertura"],
    },
  },
});
```

Hoping someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to finally get through it after trying so many different things. Turns out, the only thing that needed to be done in `setupTests.ts` was the following:

```js
import "cross-fetch/polyfill";
```

Comment: Just a note now that Node 16 is deprecated and EOL -- Node 18+ has `fetch` built-in and all the primitive types that come with it should be defined like `Response` so the `cross-fetch` polyfill above should no longer be needed

Answer (score 0):

I am currently experiencing this issue when deploying to an aws environment that runs node 16.  ( this issue was logged from building into the pipeline). I've asked middleware to update to a newer version consequently moving node versions from 16 to 18 and hopefully resolving the issue.

My local runs higher than 18 so the tests work fine there.